# how to paste codes and expressions from mathematica to forum (here)

Tags: discussion

can anyone tell me how to copy expressions from mathematica and paste them here, without any change.
so that you can exactly see what is in my mathematica window...

```
i've trouble asking question here... please help ... tnx
```

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Have a read of this first:[editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)  If you use Chrome, [this extension may help](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb).
Always favor formatted code that can be copied and pasted. For uploading images easily, check [SE-Tools](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools)

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (it belong to  [meta]) and a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)  (the question already has an answer). Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See [(1584)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) and [(1043)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043).

Comment: My boilerplate advice: "You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the {} button above the edit window. The edit window help button ? is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers...." Note that while input code in a question should be formatted text, output sometimes is better presented as an **image**.  Images can be upload with a button on the edit window or with the [uploader](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1521/)